# Hello, How to store the value "Strategy.position_avg_price" once the position is closed

Tags: pine-script

'Hello,
How to store the value "Strategy.position_avg_price" once the position is closed because in my script when storing the value, it returns NaN
I use this in myscript:
The Price_min return is OK but the Price_max return NaN
Thanks in advance for help'

```
    if LongCondition==true 
       Price_max:=strategy.position_avg_price
       Price_min:=hlc3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do it like this:

```
float Price_max = na
if LongCondition==true 
    Price_max := strategy.position_avg_price
else
    Price_max := Price_max[1]
```